# Are individual exports treated as atomic entities or modules are the atomic element?

Tags: webpack, es6-modules, tree-shaking

Conceptual question here: does webpack interprets each module export as an atomic identity, isolated from other exports, or modules ARE the atomic element?
I have this situation:

- Module A exports 3 functions: X, Y and Z. X is a pure function, and doesn't use any import, but Y and Z are not pure, and they have lot of complexity and imports that make the module enormous.
- Module B imports X (entrypoint nº1)
- Module C imports Y (entrypoint nº2)
- Module D imports Z (entrypoint nº3)

To webpack, this means that module A doesn't have deadcode, so it won't remove anything, but the question is: entry point nº1 will have the entire module A in its chunk and that's OK and expected, right?